# OpenGL ES object shape is not drawing properly in earlier version of android honeycomb

Tags: android, opengl-es, opengl-es-2.0, glsurfaceview

Im drawing a circle and even if i draw a basic shape (eg.square, diamond) using java opengl ES in android.

If I run the application in honeycomb the shape is coming fine but if I run it in gingerbread with the shape few more unnecessary points where getting drawn(it getting scattered) and if I keep on executing it rarely it comes without those points.

My Renderer class,

```
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 gl) {
     gl.glClear(GL10.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL10.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);
     gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_MODELVIEW);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glTranslatef(0, 0, -5.0f);
gl.glRotatef(-100, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);
gl.glRotatef(40, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);

mCircle= new Circle();
     Circle.setCirclePoints(1.5f,4, 1, 360);
Circle.draw(gl);

}

public void onSurfaceChanged(GL10 gl, int width, int height) {
gl.glViewport(0, 0, width, height);         
     float ratio = (float) width / height;
gl.glMatrixMode(GL10.GL_PROJECTION);
gl.glLoadIdentity();
gl.glOrthof(-6.5f, +6.5f, -6.5f, 6.5f, 6.5f, -6.5f);

  }
          public void onSurfaceCreated(GL10 gl, EGLConfig config) {
       gl.glHint(GL10.GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL10.GL_NICEST);
gl.glClearColor(0,0,0,0);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_CULL_FACE);
gl.glShadeModel(GL10.GL_SMOOTH);
gl.glEnable(GL10.GL_DEPTH_TEST);
    }
```

In my Circle Class

```
public void setCirclePoints(float radius, int slices, int stacks,
        float angle)
    ByteBuffer vbb = ByteBuffer.allocateDirect(((slices+2)* 3 * 4));
    vbb.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder());
    mSliceVertexBuffer = vbb.asFloatBuffer();

    mSliceVertexBuffer.put(0.0f);
    mSliceVertexBuffer.put(0.0f);
    mSliceVertexBuffer.put(nsign * radius);

    for (int j = 0; j <= slices; j++) {
        theta = j * dtheta;
        x = (float) 1.25f * (float) (Math.cos(theta + dupTheta));
        y = (float) Math.sin(theta + dupTheta);
        z = nsign;
        mSliceVertexBuffer.put(x * radius);
        mSliceVertexBuffer.put(y * radius);
        mSliceVertexBuffer.put(z * radius);
        } 

              }
public void draw(GL10 gl){
     gl.glEnableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
     gl.glVertexPointer(3, GL10.GL_FLOAT, 0, mSliceVertexBuffer);
     gl.glColor4f(212,21,54,34);
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0,sliceCount);
     gl.glDisableClientState(GL10.GL_VERTEX_ARRAY);
}
```

Im really clue less.. I dont know why its not drawing properly in android version <3.0.

edit: I tried to solve it, I found that when I'm trying to plot the points, few vertex are going out of the viewport(may be infinity, I dont know) in android 2.3.3, but for the same points in android 3.0 it drawing the proper shape.

Help me out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made a blunder mistake
The issue was in

```
    gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0,sliceCount);
```

where the sliceCount is total number of points x,y,z. I divided that one by 3.

```
       gl.glDrawArrays(GL10.GL_TRIANGLE_FAN, 0,sliceCount/3);
```

Answer (score 2):

> ```
> x = (float) 1.25f * (float) (Math.cos(theta + dupTheta));
> ```

What's that factor 1.25 supposed to mean? If your circle is coming out as an ellipse, then that's because your projection matrix doesn't take into account window aspect.

Comment: yes, im trying to draw a ellipse not exactly a circle.. rarely in gingerbread version it draws correctly when I keep on running the app and the remaining times it's getting distorted but in honeycomb it draws the ellipse correctly. how to solve it? thanks in advance.

Comment: hi, I tried by changing the projection matrix and modelview matrix but Im facing the problem like the circle is not smooth and points are plotted out of the viewport but for the same points it drawing smooth and proper sometimes in 2.3 and 3.0 it always comes fine.... help me out...